# Scipy optimize error

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, odeint

I have a fairly simply parameter estimation problem with ODEs I want to solve in Python. I have been using the odeint function for solving the ODEs and the scipy.optimize library for finding the parameter. When I use the odeint function by itself I get no problems but via the scipy.optimize it gives me an error RuntimeError: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2.

I do not think it is a duplicate with [How to fix the error: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664947/how-to-fix-the-error-the-array-return-by-func-must-be-one-dimensional-but-got) as I can run the odeint solver independently....

Code below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import minimize

init = [0,0]
t_end = 5
dt = 0.01
tspan = np.arange(0,t_end+dt,dt)

def my_fun(y,t,K):
    if t<=0.07:
        s = 2000
    else:
        s = 0
    return np.array([s+3.6*(y[1]-y[0]) +K*y[0], 0.38*y[0]-0.48*y[1] +K*y[1]])

def solver(t,p2):    
    y_ode = odeint(my_fun,init,t,args = (p2,))
    return y_ode

test = solver(tspan,0.01)
print(test)

y_real = solver(tspan, 0.1)

def err_fun(p):
    return np.sum((y_real-solver(tspan,p))**2)


print(err_fun(0.01))      
c0 = [0.2]

optim = minimize(err_fun,c0,method='Nelder-Mead')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `minimize` calls `err_fun` with an argument that is a one-dimensional array of length 1; `err_fun` passes this to `solver`, and `solver` passes it to `odeint`, which passes it to `my_fun` as the `K` argument.  Take a look at the difference in the shape of the output of `my_fun` when `K` is either a scalar or an array with length 1:

```
In [43]: my_fun([1, 2], 0, 0.05)  # K is a scalar.
Out[43]: array([ 2.00365e+03, -4.80000e-01])

In [44]: my_fun([1, 2], 0, np.array([0.05]))  # K is an array.
Out[44]: 
array([[ 2.00365e+03],
       [-4.80000e-01]])
```

When `K` is a one-dimensional array with length 1, `my_fun` returns an array with shape (2, 1).  That's not what `odeint` expects.

To fix this, you'll have to convert that array to a scalar somewhere in the chain of calls.  For example, you could do it immediately in `err_fun`, with something like:

```
def err_fun(p):
    if not np.isscalar(p):
        p = p[0]
    return np.sum((y_real-solver(tspan,p))**2)
```

When I do that and run your script, the code works.  Here's what I get for `optim`:

```
In [46]: optim
Out[46]: 
 final_simplex: (array([[0.1       ],
       [0.09999512]]), array([2.95795174e-22, 4.03900365e-05]))
           fun: 2.9579517415523713e-22
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 34
           nit: 17
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([0.1])
```